# Android Theme for webview month control

Tags: android, webview, themes

In my app I have a webview that uses the "input type=month" control but the window displayed to select a month is dark, while a similar window displayed to select a "select option" is white.

What should I do in the themes to have it white ?

[image: input type month]

Comment: You should look at app/widgets theme properties. And i am sure there will be different widgets on different api levels of android i.e. material design

Comment: I have many misunderstandings about themes : I use Appcelerator, AppCompat, etc. And I confess that I know nothing about android themes. May the datePickerDialogTheme be helpful ? What should I do with this information ?

Comment: Yes. About datePickerTheme. Xml definitions of them are in files named **styles.xml** or they can be manually writed in code (aka java). Use google search:)